# remove duplicates in python

Tags: python, sql

I'm looking to remove the names that are repeated.

My code is connected to retrieve information from SQL server to Python.

```
def get_all_artist():
    query="SELECT artist_name FROM Sheet1"
    all_artist = execute_read_query (conn, query)
    for artist_record in all_artist:
        print(str(artist_record[0]))
    return (all_artist)
```

The artist_name that I am retrieving on SQL are:

```
BTS
BTS
BTS
TWICE
TWICE
TWICE
TWICE
TWICE
HEIZE
HEIZE
KHALID
KHALID
KHALID
ERIC CHOU
ERIC CHOU
ERIC CHOU
SAM SMITH
SAM SMITH
SAM SMITH
AGUST D
```

However, I'd only like to remove the duplicates on Python without removing any rows in my SQL table:

```
BTS
TWICE
HEIZE
KHALID
ERIC CHOU
SAM SMITH
AGUST D
```

Comment: update your SQL query like: `"SELECT UNIQUE artist_name FROM Sheet1"`

Comment: why don't u use distinct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use This Function and It Will Be work:

```
def get_all_artist():
    query="SELECT distinct artist_name FROM Sheet1"
    all_artist = execute_read_query (conn, query)
    for artist_record in all_artist:
        print(str(artist_record[0]))
    return (all_artist)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `distinct`:

```
select distinct artist_name from sheet1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a SQL query, the statement for removing repetition is `DISTINCT`:

```
query="SELECT DISTINCT artist_name FROM Sheet1"
```